# Git: Failed to deploy application: Could not find app name

Tags: eclipse, git, heroku, repository, init

I want to deploy a Java application to  Heroku from Eclipse. When I want to deploy the app, the build fails. There comes the error message:

*Failed to deploy application: Could not find app name: Git repo not found. Did you init one before creating your app?*

In my console in the folder of the project I already entered "git init". In the folder of the project there exists no .git folder

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you host your code on github, heroku has a very simple integration, check [this docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration)

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow a sequence of steps to get your code deployed. It includes `init`, `add`, `commit`, `add remote`, `push`, `pull`, etc.

Refer [simple git tutorial](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1) and [Heroku's documentation for deployment through Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#tracking-your-app-in-git).